# su to 'superuser system' fails even when root tries it, even after passwd setting

Tags: sudo, su

In order to minimise risk of fouling up the wife's machine, I have installed using her id, then created user *userme*, a guestlike user without sudoers privileges, and *userME*, a system user without shell, but with sudoers - I didn't want to clutter the login screen too much with my name on her machine ...
So, I am now trying to install stuff for *userme* which require root privileges to use.
'su thewife' results in the correct 'whoami', but 'su userME' gives 'whoami'='userme', yet without authentification failure!
'sudo su userME' from userme fails for lack of sudoers privileges and fails without authentification error again when attempted from 'su thewife'
*userME* can login on tty1 without problems.
Does the lack of sudoers rights cascade? I've obviously done something wrong, but what? I could add *userme* to sudoers group, but that defeats the object of having 2 separate logins.

```
userme@notebook$ su userME
userme@notebook$ whoami
userme
userme@notebook$ su thewife
Password:
thewife@notebook$ whoami
thewife
thewife@notebook$ su userME
Password:
thewife@notebook$ whoami
thewife
sudo -s
Password:
root@notebook# whoami
root
root@notebook# su userME
root@notebook# whoami
root
root@notebook# su - userME
root@notebook# whoami
root

uname -a
Linux notebook 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How exactly did you crate *"a system user without shell"*? If you set the login shell to `/bin/false`, then what you're seeing is entirely normal. See for example [What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10867/65304)

Comment: `su` is the old way, use `sudo` - it's easier to control `man sudo`;man sudo_root`. You'll find that the userid that you first installed is a member of the `admin` group, and CAN `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks to @steeldriver

I edited `/etc/passwd` and removed the `/bin/false` leaving that column blank. The result is exactly what I wanted, namely: 

...login using `su`, login using `tty`, but no listing on logins screen (except for my impotent other login, with no `sudoers`). 

I can now remove all of the `echo`s from `.bashrc` and `.profile` :-)